# Run Liferay Dynamic Scheduler on Specific Date and Time

Tags: java, triggers, liferay, liferay-6

I am trying to call Liferay Trigger on hourly basis and it is working successfully using this [link](http://pmkathiria.blogspot.in/2013/06/how-to-write-simplecron-scheduler-in.html)

But now **I want to dynamic execute Trigger only on Start & End DateTime set by user in Database**

**Scheduler Table**

```
schedulerId    schedulerStartDateTime    schedulerEndDateTime    blockId
1              05/11/2016  01:00         05/13/2016  02:00       11011
2              05/12/2016  13:00         05/16/2016  16:30       11012
3              05/11/2016  20:15         05/20/2016  22:00       11013
```

Any help would be appreciated.

I have read from [this Post](https://web.liferay.com/community/forums/-/message_boards/view_message/20717776) that It is working using SchedulerEntry but don't know how to and where to utilize this Class.

Answer (score 0):

An approach that I use in my work is like below:

first I configure in liferay-portlet.xml the scheduler like below:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE liferay-portlet-app PUBLIC "-//Liferay//DTD Portlet Application 6.2.0//EN" "http://www.liferay.com/dtd/liferay-portlet-app_6_2_0.dtd">

<liferay-portlet-app>
    <portlet>
        <portlet-name>your-portelt</portlet-name>
        <icon>/icon.png</icon>
        <scheduler-entry>
            <scheduler-event-listener-class>your.class.that.implements.messagelistener</scheduler-event-listener-class>
            <trigger>
                <cron>
                    <cron-trigger-value>.... your cron</cron-trigger-value>
                </cron>
            </trigger>
        </scheduler-entry>
    ...
    </portlet>
    ...
</liferay-portlet-app>
```

then I implement the my busines logic of sheduler in a class that i reference in scheduler-event-listener-class tag.

```
public class YourManageScheduler implements MessageListener {

        @Override
        public void receive(Message message) throws MessageListenerException {
            User user = ....
            PermissionChecker permissionChecker = PermissionCheckerFactoryUtil.getPermissionCheckerFactory().create(user);
            PermissionThreadLocal.setPermissionChecker(permissionChecker);
            // your logic
            ...       
 // your logic
          ....
        }

...
    }
```

An important thing if you use some api that preform PermissionCheker you have configure the permision cheker in your thread local or try to use api that don't requred permission cheker. The key point hear is that in this case the job start in async way and no users are logged therfore no permission cheker is configured in MessageListener thread.

I hope that this can help you